# Jquery cannot read disable elements

Tags: jquery

I have HTML like this :

```
<li class="MostViewedProducts">
    <input class="MostViewedProductsi" type="checkbox" checked="checked"/>
    <span class="labels">Some Text</span>
    <a class="fancybox" href="#inline40" id="tozih"></a>
</li>
```

and some Jquery like this :

```
$('.MostViewedProductsi').attr('disabled', true);
var $form = $('*');
```

My Question is :

When I Disable the Class , the Jquery can't read the element and pass it by GET or POST to the PHP file, and when I make the class -MostViewedProducts- read only , the user can still change the check box.

What solution can I use ?

Comment: What you mean by "Disable the class" ? remove it ?

Comment: Clarify please what: _" the Jquery can't read the element and pass it"_ means. Pass it to where? how are you trying to read?

Comment: if you dont want people to `edit` you input fields and send the data to backend then use `readonly`

Comment: Show us the full code. Your question is incomplete.

Comment: You have no idea how long the full code is . I correct the question .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is by design of HTML - no `disabled` elements are passed in a GET or POST.

To remedy this you could remove the `disabled` attribute on submission of the form so that the elements' value can be posted.

Comment: @gdoron true, but he also says 'jQuery can't pass it' implying some kind of POST is being made. I'll leave this answer until the OP clarifies what he's trying to do.

Comment: This is the sloution witch i want , excuse me for my lake of description , i edit the question to be more understandable . thanks.

Comment: @RezaMarefaty. It still doesn't too much sense, as jQuery CAN read disabled elements. Glad Rory could help you. +1.

Answer (score 1):

Two options:

```
$('.MostViewedProductsi').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
$('.MostViewedProductsi').prop('disabled', true); // jQuery version 1.6+
```

Answer (score 0):

You use wrong value of attribute `disabled` see here for more information:

[HTML `<input>` disabled Attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_disabled.asp)